# Extract primitive value from Keras tensor that only contains it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this tensor:

```
Tensor("strided_slice_8:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

I want to print the value of the float32 that is inside.
For instance, if the tensor contains 29.3 I would like to get the Python native value 29.3 or "29.3".

`tf.keras.backend.get_value(tensor)` works but unfortunately it is extremely **slow** (about 10 seconds), it seems that it performs the calculation again just to get that value out. `tensor.eval()` is equally slow. At that point I have already run `model.predict` and printed all results so there should be nothing left to calculate.

Is there a way to get the result within milliseconds?

Comment: Are you asking about an optimized method to extract ? Seems that you already have the solution.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan: I made the question clearer, thanks!